# Function in java does not finish

Tags: java

Greetings,

this is my very first question and I just do programming as a hobby so keep that in mind when trying to help me, please.

I have a function that tries to read the centre point of a crosshair. Something like a position finder in a game. The code looks like this:

```
public static Point location(BufferedImage image) {
        int pixelLeft;
        int pixelTop;
        Point point = new Point();

        for (int i = Main.RADAR_TOP+1; i < Main.RADAR_BOTTOM; i++) {
            pixelLeft = image.getRGB(Main.RADAR_LEFT+7, i);
            if ((((pixelLeft>>16) & 0xff) > 35 &&
                  ((pixelLeft>>8) & 0xff) > 35 &&
                  ((pixelLeft) & 0xff) > 35)){
                point.y = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int j = Main.RADAR_LEFT+1; j < Main.RADAR_RIGHT; j++) {
            pixelTop = image.getRGB(j, Main.RADAR_TOP+5);
            if ((((pixelTop>>16) & 0xff) > 35 && 
                  ((pixelTop>>8) & 0xff) > 35 && 
                  ((pixelTop) & 0xff) > 35)){
                point.x = j;
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("location: "+point.x+","+point.y);
/**        lastX = point.x;
        lastY = point.y;*/
        return point;
    }
```

What happens is that at times, this function simply does not return control to the main application. Basically it gets stuck running. Therefore the last comment in the function to do a check. I first thought that maybe it had something to do with reading static members of the class where the function resides so I commented those out as you can see at the end. The problem still occurs though.

I can't really see or think of any reason for this behaviour. I'll appreciate very much any ideas or comments that could point me to a mistake or something.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out other parts of the code? I would normally suspect the loops, but they do look okay at a first glance...

Comment: depending on the size of your image, this may simply be very slow. have you tried putting a System.out.println into the loops and see if it really ever stops running or just runs for a very long time?

Comment: also, what are the values of RADAR_[BOTTOM, ...], and what is the size of your image? Is there any chance you start looking for RGB values outside your actual image dimensions? I could image that could lock up the program if something's going particularly wrong.

Comment: Use a debugger, step through the code, insert breakpoints, watch values, etc. These are powerful debugging tools, and now would be a great time to learn how to use them.

Comment: Also, use logging tools.  Java has a built-in in `java.util.logging`, but there are some better alternatives, such as slf4j ( if you start from scratch I suggest this ) and log4j.

Comment: I haven't really commented out any other parts. I did check RADAR_RIGHT instead of RADAR_LEFT for the 1st loop. Still the same. I also added comments before entering the for-loop and inside. All are printed so it seems like the loops are finished. In fact, the location returned with the last comment is indeed the crosshair's centre! The image is always less than 140Kb obtained from a printscreen of the desktop (1280x800) and the constants RADAR_TOP = 120, RADAR_BOTTOM = 695, RADAR_LEFT = 120 and RADAR_RIGHT = 1140.

Comment: @Juan - then the problem is really elsewhere, then it's not this method that freezes your application.

Comment: Andread_D, you were totally right and your comment made me think outside the box (the box being that function in this case). The problem was that the location function was called by a second function and this second function was inside a case-statement where I missed the break. That's why the application "got stuck". Thank you very much and to all the other guys for the help. I really appreciate you took time to look into my question!

Comment: @Juan why don't you provide the correct answer yourself, now that you know it. After two days you will be able to accept it, thus marking this question as answered. (And perhaps receiving an upvote or two)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the location function was called by a second function and this second function was inside a case-statement where I missed the break. That's why the application "got stuck".

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that Main.RADAR_TOP is less then Main.RADAR_BOTTOM ?
Else the forloop should spin for a while (a long while..)